# Calling saxon from python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, saxon

I am trying to call saxon from python. Before I was using os.system(command) in python 2.x and everything worked fine, but something has changed between 2.7 and 3.7. My code no longer works. I have tried using "subprocess.call(command)" and "subprocess.run(command)", but neither seems to work. Here's what was working before:

```
command = "java -jar C:\\saxon\\saxon9he.jar -o:\"" + directory + "\\_new.xml\" " + "-xsl:\"" + xslDir + "\" -s:\"" + newFile + "\""
os.system(command)
```

The command runs fine in a cmd prompt (when I replace the variables with actual files). But nothing is working in 3.7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's always a good idea to say how it fails.... Running the transformation via a shell command is always going to be very inefficient, even if you can get it to work (because of the cost of bringing up a Java VM, compiling the stylesheet, etc etc). Using the new Python language binding in Saxon/C will be much better; or doing the transformation via an HTTP request to a REST transformation service also works well.

Comment: Basically a cmd window quickly pops up, then closes, and the anticipated new XML file does not get created.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the latest Saxon/C version supports Python 3. See: details: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Comment: I went through the process, but when I run the ```py saxon-setup.py build_ext -if``` command I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "saxon-setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

```

Comment: Are you using Linux or windows? In any case cython most be installed to build Saxon/C for python. See: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!starting/installingpython

Comment: I'm on Windows and I do have cython installed. I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Cython for python 3? Also it has to be run in powershell as mentioned in the doc